# Import macro in word - Visual Basic Error

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing an academic paper. The organization of the conference gave me a list of macro to use in order to write the paper.
When I try to active the macros in word I get this error:

[image]

Which says that I have an undefined user defined type. What should I do?
I am sorry but I am really a newbie, never used Visual Basic before.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_Open()
Dim ur  As UndoRecord
Dim objField  As Field

On Error Resume Next
Set ur = Application.UndoRecord
ur.StartCustomRecord "Update all fields"
'Update fields
For Each objField In ActiveDocument.Fields
   If objField.Type = wdFieldSequence Then
      objField.Update
   End If
Next
ur.EndCustomRecord
'If no other change is made (except for updating the fields), allow closing without saving
ActiveDocument.Saved = True
'Check for standard page setup
RestorePageSetup

End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't previously heard of the `UndoRecord` object type, but perhaps [**this link**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/word/concepts/working-with-word/working-with-the-undorecord-object) will give some insight. I assume you're missing a reference to an Object Library...?

Comment: Is this Visual Basic (eg, [tag:vb.net]) or is it [tag:vba]?  If VBA, I assume it's in [tag:ms-word]? If you add a few more relevant tags to your question it will get more attention.  Also, it's best to copy and paste the code into the question instead of just an image of it.  (See "[ask]" as well as "how to create an [mcve]".)

Comment: Ok question edit done, i don't know how to add a Library

Comment: The procedure `RestorePageSetup` is not defined. Find that procedure

Comment: You need to ask the conference organiser for better instructions on how to install and use the macros.

Comment: To view the VBA library references, go to the VBA editor (Alt-F11) and then Alt-T, R to see a dialog box.  You may be shown a missing library reference.

Comment: Which version of Word are you using? Which line of code is triggering the error? Note: comment out the line `On Error Resume Next` as this may be masking the true problem. And, as someone else said, we also need to see `RestorePageSetup` - that's not a Word command, that's code this macro is trying to find.

Comment: @Freeflow macros are working on another pc by doing the installation in the same way so i think that word is the problem because on this pc i am using a different version. By the way i am using Word 2007

Comment: The problem is related to the word version. I update Word to 2017 and the marcos are working.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to my word version, updated from 2007 to 2017 and macros are working.